# add_definitions() Package Exportation

Tags: ros, catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

I have some variables I declared in my CMakeList in one package.
For example, I create the constant:

```
add_definitions(-DTRAINED_DATA_PATH="${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/trained_data")
```

How can I make it available to other ROS packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243016/add_definitions()-package-exportation/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to look into Catkin's [CFG_EXTRA](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin_package) feature.

See [How to export non-standard include directories in catkin?](http://answers.ros.org/question/93266) for an answer by @William that explains how to do this (this deals with include directories specifically, but the principle is the same. Just place an `add_definitions(..)` in your extras file, and be careful with `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`, as it may not have the same value (or be even defined) in the devel and install spaces).

Btw: using (ROS) parameters is a bit more flexible than using hard-coded, compile time constants, as it allows you to specify the location of things using a bit of configuration. That would also remove the need for exporting the define. If you have the option (ie: this is not a completely stand-alone library that is supposed to work without ROS), I'd use that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-09-09**:
I agree with the parameters suggestions. That will avoid recompilation every time

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-09-12**:
Actually, how do you create this in a config file by using appropriate project paths?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-13**:
The answer by @William I linked should show you an example.